# Find Most recent folder, copy files to destination folder

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a way to find the most recent folder, copy the files inside to a destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rootFolder = "C:\root"
dstFolder  = "C:\dst"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set mostRecent = FindMostRecent(fso.GetFolder(rootFolder))
For Each f In mostRecent.Files
  f.Copy fso.BuildPath(dstFolder, f.Name)
Next

Function FindMostRecent(fldr)
  Set mrf = fldr
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Set mrsf = FindMostRecent(sf)
    If mrsf.DateLastModified > mrf.DateLastModified Then Set mrf = mrsf
  Next
  Set FindMostRecent = mrf
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar Wiechers  That looks better than what I had. However, when I run it from cmd prompt, call test.vbs nothing happens.  Lastly, where do I set the destination folder? Thanks again!

Comment: `cls

set knownpath=C:\a

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /od /b "%knownpath%"') do (
    set name=%%a
)


copy "%knownpath%\%name%" "C:\b"`  I found this to work, thanks!

Comment: Your batch solution will only check the immediate subfolders of `%knownpath%`. It won't look any deeper. Anyway, the reason why you didn't see anything was because my script just located the most recently changed folder. It didn't actually do anything with it. I added code for copying the files to some other folder now.

Answer (score 0):

I see you met some difficulties with passing your folders as arguments. Ansgar Wiechers's example showed how to do that with hard-coded values. That we do usually in our answers for simplicity sake.

```
rootFolder = "C:\root"    'target folder (where to search)
dstFolder  = "C:\dst"     'destionation (where to copy)
```

But if you prefer to pass them dynamical like...

```
CScript my_task.vbs C:\root C:\dst
```

...then include this at the beginning of your .vbs file:

```
With WScript.Arguments
    If .Count < 2 Then WScript.Quit(-1)
    rootFolder = .Item(0)
    dstFolder  = .Item(1)
End With
```

Next, by reading your comments, seems to me you need just the immediate subfolders, and if so, as am not so good in batch scripting, I'll do something like this:

```
tmpFile    = "result.txt" 'temp file
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .CurrentDirectory = rootFolder
    .Run "CMD /C DIR /A:D /B /O:-D /T:C > " & tmpFile, 0, True
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        With .OpenTextFile(tmpFile)
            mostRecent = .ReadLine
        End With
        .GetFile(tmpFile).Delete
    End With
    .CurrentDirectory = mostRecent
    .Run "CMD /C COPY *.* " & dstFolder, 0, False
End With
```

Used DIR switches:

```
/A:D  = attributes Directory
/B    = bare format
/O:-D = order by date/time (newly first)
/O:D  = order by date/time (oldest first)
/T:C  = sort by Creation
/T:A  = sort by Last Access
/T:W  = sort by Last Written
```