# How do I get the supplied VBScript to copy files for my folders?

Tags: vbscript

I want to find the most recent folder and copy files to destination folder with vbsscript.

This is done [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577945/vb-script-find-most-recent-folder-copy-files-to-destination-folder?rq=1), but the solution provided does not work for me.

Ansgar Wiechers provided this code.

```
rootFolder = "C:\root"
dstFolder  = "C:\dst"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set mostRecent = FindMostRecent(fso.GetFolder(rootFolder))
For Each f In mostRecent
  f.Copy fso.BuildPath(dstFolder, f.Name)
Next

Function FindMostRecent(fldr)
  Set mrf = fldr
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Set mrsf = FindMostRecent(sf)
    If mrsf.DateLastModified > mrf.DateLastModified Then Set mrf = mrsf
  Next
  Set FindMostRecent = mrf
End Function
```

When changing first line to `rootFolder = "D:\"` and second to
`dstFolder  = "C:\"`, I get the following error:

```
Script: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\new 456 82.vbs
Line:   14
Char:   5
Error:  Object required: 'FindMostRecent(...)'
Code:   800A01A8
Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Changing root to `D:\Files` and destination to `C:\test` gives:

```
Script: C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\new 456 8.vbs
Line:   7
Char:   1
Error:  Object doesn't support this property or method
Code:   800A01B6
Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

I have not yet incorporated the `copy` command found in the same thread:

```
cls set knownpath=C:\a for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /od /b "%knownpath%"') do ( set name=%%a )         copy "%knownpath%\%name%" "C:\b"
```

I have no idea where in the script I should place the command.  I tried right after `Set FindMostRecent = mrf` on a new line, but I get another error.  Tried after `End` function too, and get another error.

I need this broken down to me as if I was a five year old.

edit: ok so now that the main code is working I'm trying to insert the copy command. This is what I tried so far and it's giving me error.

```
    rootFolder = "D:\test"
    dstFolder  = "D:\test2"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set mostRecent = FindMostRecent(fso.GetFolder(rootFolder))
    For Each f In mostRecent.Files
      f.Copy fso.BuildPath(dstFolder, f.Name)
    Next

    Function FindMostRecent(fldr)
      Set mrf = fldr
      For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
        Set mrsf = FindMostRecent(sf)
        If mrsf.DateLastModified > mrf.DateLastModified Then Set mrf = mrsf
      Next
      Set FindMostRecent = mrf
    End Function
    cls set knownpath="D:\test" for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /od /b "%knownpath%"') do ( set name=%%a ) copy "%knownpath%\%name%" "D:\test2"
```

EDIT2:

```
rootFolder = "D:\Files"
dstFolder  = "D:\test"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set mostRecent = FindMostRecent(fso.GetFolder(rootFolder))
mostRecent.Copy dstFolder

Function FindMostRecent(fldr)
  Set mrf = fldr
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Set mrsf = FindMostRecent(sf)
    If mrsf.DateLastModified > mrf.DateLastModified Then Set mrf = mrsf
  Next
  Set FindMostRecent = mrf
End Function
```

Comment: The last line in your updated script is a bunch of **batch** commands. These will certainly generate a syntax error when used in a **VBScript**.

Comment: ah ok, silly me, reading sloppy. But your code (that is the one I provided in the edit minus the last line, the batch command) doesn't copy anything.

Comment: Which folder is returned as the most recent? Does it contain any files? Add a line `WScript.Echo mostRecent.Path` before the loop and a line `WScript.Echo f.Path` inside the loop with the copy command.

Comment: OK, I mispoke. It does copy, however it copies only files that are directly in the root folder. Folders are not being copied. Also more than one files are being copied, and they have different date modified. Adding WScript.Echo mostRecent.Path before For Each f In mostRecent.Files and WScript.Echo f.Path after f.Copy fso.BuildPath(dstFolder, f.Name) gives a message - D:\test, then D:\test\asd.txt etc with files that are in D:\test. It also includes a folder inside D:\test. I created a new folder in root folder, now script only gives message about that folder and file in it.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what the script does: find the most recently modified folder and copy the files from it. Of course it doesn't copy files from a subfolder, because that folder obviously is not the one that was most recently modified. If you want the script to do something different, please specify your requirements in more detail. What do you want to copy, and what distinguishes what you want to copy from what you don't want to copy?

Comment: I want it to find the most recent folder (in the root directory), and copy that and only that folder, with all it's content in it with mantined structure.

Comment: Define "only that folder". It's usually quite pointless to copy just a folder, because you can just as well create it in the destination, so I'm going to assume that you actually want to copy the folder's content. Does that include subfolders and files in subfolders as well? If so, you could simply drop the loop and use `mostRecent.Copy dstFolder`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ment. Now it's finally working the way I originally wanted it to! Thank you very much.  A progress bar of the copy would be nice, or some way to visually know that the copy is complete.  A sound at finished would be nice as well. I will try google first and then get back if I can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Hmmm, something is wrong. I tried it again with different root, which is a folder where I keep all downloaded files, and destination, and it's copying lots of folders instead of only one - all with different date modified :S. Going to bed now, will pick it up tomorrow. To be clear I'm making another edit to question with the code I'm currently running.

Comment: To be clear, what I want the script to do is copy based on latest date modified and preferably time as well. So that only the folder that is on top when sorting after Date Modified in windows gets copied. I hope that's what we've been talking about the whole time.

Comment: I added another answer to reflect the requirements you outlined.

Answer (score 1):

What the code does:

`FindMostRecent()` is a recursive (i.e. self-referencing) function that returns the most recently modified folder in the folder tree under the given root folder.

If the given folder does not contain subfolders, the current folder is the most recent folder, so the function defaults to the current folder by setting `mrf = fldr`.

If the folder contains subfolders, the most recent folder from each subfolder tree is determined by a recursive call (`FindMostRecent(sf)`). The "last modified" date from that folder (`mrsf`) is compared to the "last modified" date of the current most recent folder (`mrf`). If `mrsf` is more recent than `mrf`, the latter is replaced with the former.

When each existing subfolder has been checked (if any), `mrf` contains the most recent folder from the folder tree under `fldr`, which is then returned to the caller.

---

As for the errors, try adding some debugging code to the function:

```
Function FindMostRecent(fldr)
  Set mrf = fldr
  WScript.Echo "TypeName(mrf) = " & TypeName(mrf)
  WScript.Echo "mrf = " & mrf.Name
  WScript.Echo mrf.Path
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Set mrsf = FindMostRecent(sf)
    On Error Resume Next
    If mrsf.DateLastModified > mrf.DateLastModified Then Set mrf = mrsf
    If Err Then
      WScript.Echo "TypeName(mrsf) = " & TypeName(mrsf)
      WScript.Echo "mrsf = " & mrsf.Name
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
  Next
  Set FindMostRecent = mrf
End Function
```

That should help you track down at which point the error occurs.

Comment: With the debugging code I get this message when running script: 
                                                                                                                          
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
TypeName(mrf) = Folder

Comment: Is that all? Just one type and then nothing more? No folder name? No errors? What is the name of the folder you pass into the function? Does your user have permission to access it?

Comment: (my source folder is test 
my destination folder is test2)

Then when clicking ok:

mrf = test

OK again gives:
D:\test

then:

TypeName(mrf) = Folder

then:

mrf = "name of folder in test"

Then:

D:\test\"name of folder in test"

TheN:

D:\test\"name of folder in test"

then: 

mrf = TempDir

Then this again:

D:\test\"name of folder"\TempDir

I can continue clicking OK and finally it gives:


Script: C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\v1.vbs
Line: 7
Char: 1
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Code: 800A01B6
Source:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Comment: Yes I am full admin on this machine, and never had any troubles with moving/copying/deleting filse on my D: drive, only C: drive and it's not involved

Comment: Line 7 in the script from your question is `For Each f In mostRecent`. That line should actually read `For Each f In mostRecent.Files`. `mostRecent` is a folder object and as such not enumerable.

Comment: What the hell, how did that happen.. Anyway, now just running code without the copy part gives no errors. Where do I put the copy command? Tried on new line after End function, error. Also tried on the line before end function, error as well. I changed knownpath=C:\a to knownpath=D:\test and copy "%knownpath%\%name%" "C:\b" to copy "%knownpath%\%name%" "D:\test2"
Script: C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\v2.vbs
Line: 19
Char: 5
Error: Syntax error
Code: 800A03EA

Comment: That was actually my mistake. I missed adding the `.Files` when I updated the answer you took the code from with that loop. As for the new error you're getting: I'm not going to guess what line 19 in `v2.vbs` might be. Please update your question with that script.

Comment: The full script is now included in the original question after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The following will copy the most recently modified folder from the `rootFolder` tree (which could be `rootFolder` itself!) to `dstFolder`:

```
rootFolder = "D:\Files"
dstFolder  = "D:\test"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set mostRecent = FindMostRecent(fso.GetFolder(rootFolder))
mostRecent.Copy dstFolder

Function FindMostRecent(fldr)
  Set mrf = fldr
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Set mrsf = FindMostRecent(sf)
    If mrsf.DateLastModified > mrf.DateLastModified Then Set mrf = mrsf
  Next
  Set FindMostRecent = mrf
End Function
```

Note that with `dstFolder  = "D:\test"` the instruction `mostRecent.Copy dstFolder` will copy the *content* of `mostRecent` to the destination folder:

```
Before:

  D:\
  +-Files\
  | +-foo.txt
  | `-bar\
  `-test\

After:

  D:\
  +-Files\
  | +-foo.txt
  | `-bar\
  `-test\
    +-foo.txt
    `-bar\
```

If you want to copy the entire `mostRecent` folder:

```
Before:

  D:\
  +-Files\
  | +-foo.txt
  | `-bar\
  `-test\

After:

  D:\
  +-Files\
  | +-foo.txt
  | `-bar\
  `-test\
    `-Files\
      +-foo.txt
      `-bar\
```

the destination must have a trailing backslash:

```
mostRecent.Copy dstFolder & "\"
```

Comment: ok, well I never want it to copy the entire root folder itself, only the folder most recently modified inside the root folder. Please change the code so that the script won't do that.

Comment: SO is not a "write code for me free" site. Consider this your homework.